# Как передать данные из одного компонента в другой при событии

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, rxjs

У меня есть `app.component.html`:

```html
<div class="container">
  <app-filter (filter)="applyFilter($event)"></app-filter>
  <app-table [elementData]="elementData" [filter]="filter"></app-table>
</div>
```

Компонент `app-filter` это фильтр поиска. Когда срабатывает `(filter)` он возвращает объект с информацией о фильтре.
В данном случае в `app.component.ts` функция `applyFilter` срабатывает, когда происходит фильтрация в `app-filter`.
Как я могу сделать так, чтобы при фильтрации данные передавались в `app-table` и при этом, это происходило в какой-то функции, чтобы это можно было отслеживать?
[Ссылка](https://github.com/mihinov/angular-filter/commit/1f09dc6c6c60bfe3fd932250dd8cac2717dbc472) на `app-component`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вашу проблему, можно воспользоваться классом Subject из модуля rxjs:

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

export class Filter {
    changed$ = new Subject<Filter>();

    emitChanged() {
        this.changed$.next(this);
    }
}
```

Тогда внутри компонента app-table подключаем слушателя к объекту фильтра:

```
export class TableComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnInit {

    private filters: Filter[];

    @Input() set filter(filter: Filter) {
        filter.changed$.subscribe( (filterObject) => {
           //...
        });
        this.filters.push(filter);
    }
}
```

Comment: а что означает `@Input set`?

Comment: @Михаил Камахин это так называемый  сеттер https://learn.javascript.ru/descriptors-getters-setters

Comment: У Subject нету метода emit

Comment: @МихаилКамахин да `next(this)`, перепутал с EventEmitter'ом

Answer (score 0):

В общем и целом, Александр прав, но я вижу большое пространство для запутывания Михаила.

Можно добиться того же самого результата просто использовав указанный Александром сеттер

```typescript
export class TableComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnInit {

    private filters: Filter[];

    @Input() set filter(filter: Filter) {
        // Выполнение какой-либо операции 
        this.filters.push(filter);
    }
}
```

Почему так - метод `applyFilter(filter: Filter)` обновляет свойство `app-component` компонента `filter`.

```
public applyFilter(filter: Filter) {
    this.filter = filter;
}
```

ChangeDetector поймёт что фильтр изменился и затем передаст этот тик в компонент таблицы, которая поймает изменения с помощью вышеуказанного сеттера.

Также можно написать провайдер, который `AppComponent` будет провайдить в себя, а дочерний компонент `TableComponent` будет его получать и использовать для показа, но это более продвинутая тема